# Astrophysical Jet Size?

Tags: black-hole, gravity, general-relativity, accretion-discs, astronomical-jet

I am wondering about what is the estimated size of astrophysical jet that shoots out from a black hole, I don’t know if it is determined by the size of a black hole.

What would classify a black hole that is able to have at least 10 planets orbit it? Is it considered stellar?

If so, what would the estimated astrophysical jet or quasar be?

Comment: Astrophysical jets are so complicated, there's likely not going to be a good answer here. The size of the jet depends on so many factors such as the mass of the central body, the strength of the magnetic field, the amount of inflow from the accretion disk, the density of the medium the jet is shooting into, the wavelength you're looking at the jet with, and so much more... Such a question could be a full thesis.

Comment: @zephyr , thanks for your input on the matter, I thought there were pieces of information that shows the 3C 273 star has length of 100000 AU.

Comment: Do you mean quazar jets? They can tell the size of the jets, but they don't know the physical process and masses involved in making them. No maths consensus on the mass. Some jets are many 1000ds light years long. black holes are not stellar. planets are not stellar. they are their own object type. a black hole of stellar mass can have planets like a star. they would be cold and exotic planets, and the proto-planetary disk would be made of odd matter.

Comment: Quasars were a lot more common 10bn light years away, when free hydrogen was much more available to wander into accretion disks. The distance of them is a barrier to measuring the masses of the galaxies and BH's involved.

Comment: Thank you for you input on the question, this is something that I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple categories of Black Hole powered astrophysical jets:

1. Microquasars: As their name implies, they are somewhat like a highly scaled-downed version of quasars, but unlike quasars, they are powered by accretion from a donor star. They contain stellar-mass black holes.
2. Quasars: They are huge systems of accretion disk(s) around supermassive black holes.  They are found in the centers of galaxies, and are very powerful, enough to outshine their host galaxies.

The size of jets depends on the type: microquasars have jets only a few light years long, whereas quasars have jets millions of light years long.

The size of the jets depends on the mass of the Black hole and the magnetic field of the black hole and the magnetic field of the accretion disk.